# This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play

Tags: android, apk, in-app-billing, google-play

When I try to run my application with in-app billing I am getting the error: "This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information".

I have the billing permission already in the Manifest file and I have a signed .apk uploaded as a draft onto Google Play and I have also installed that same signed apk onto my phone.

Any help on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have this problem on real device, but not on emulator.

I install the same build on the emulator and device. I logged in as the same user on both emulator and device.

On device I got this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing error, on emulator everything works normally and dialog with test card appears.

What the difference?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Ahh found the solution after trying for a couple of hours.

1. Google takes a while to process applications and update them to their servers, for me it takes about half a day. So after saving the apk as a draft on Google Play, you must wait a few hours  before the in-app products will respond normally and allow for regular purchases.
2. Export and sign APK. Unsigned APK trying to make purchases will get error.

Comment: Wow, is this serious? Just ran into the same problem. Did everything Google asked me to do in order to test in-app billing, but still getting the same evasive error message. I guess I'll have to wait and see. But does Google really expect us developers to wait hours each time we need to update our app in order to implement in-app billing? It seems quite inappropriate to me, to say the least.

Comment: Can you test while connected to Android Studio / running while connected to the debugger? Or do you need to install the release apk via USB?

Comment: Is there an easier way to test the purchase process other than, Android Tools > Export signed project... etc, then manually copy APK across to device, Test, .... repeat? I must be missing something?

Comment: Seriously, I cannot use the application with debug certificate and test In-App Billing?

Comment: Even with the signed apk installed, I'm still getting this error.

Comment: It seems like the testing device has to have the exact same APK installed that is in Google Play. It doesn't need to be in production, beta works too. But this makes developing very hard. To test it, you have to upload the APK to Google Play, and it takes them hours to refresh. So, if I just want to add one logger call, I need to wait hours for it to work. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that you CAN use debug builds, straight from your IDE as you are working. You just need to change the debug keystore to one that matches your release store. See this post for more information on how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886814/configure-eclipse-to-use-signed-keystore

Comment: I export a signed APK, and run it manually on my device, the problem solved. 10x!

Comment: @gatekeeper
will it also take half day if I do some changes in IAP and test it in my Android phone without updating to Google play?

Comment: @gatekeeper Do you happen to know which countries that I manually need to report and pay VAT tax for on In-app billing with Google? I have read that Japan needs manually reporting. Anyone else? I would be happy If you could read/answer my Q at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506835/android-in-app-billing-vat-tax

Comment: For Android Studio users (not eclipse), follow steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-is-debug-keystore-in-android-studio/39330177

Answer (score 410):

This error may be caused by several reasons.

Here is the list of requirements for the Google IAB testing.

Prerequisites:

1. AndroidManifest must include **"com.android.vending.BILLING" permission**.
2. APK is built in **release mode**.
3. APK is **signed** with the **release certificate(s)**. (Important: with "App Signing by Google Play" it only works if you download directly from GooglePlayStore!)
4. APK is uploaded to **alpha/beta distribution** channel (previously - as a draft) to the developer console at least once. (takes some time **~2h-24h**).
5. IAB **products are published** and their status set to **active**.
6. **Test account(s) is added** in developer console.

Testing requirements:

1. Test APK has the **same versionCode** as the one uploaded to developer console.
2. Test APK is **signed** with the **same certificate(s)** as the one uploaded to dev.console.
3. **Test account** (not developer) - is the **main account** on the device. (Main account might be not necessary - according to [@MinosL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571949/minosl) comment)
4. **Test account is opted-in** as a tester and it's **linked to a valid payment method**.  ([@Kyone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223102/kyone))

P.S: **Debugging with release certificate**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15754187/1321401 (Thnx [@dipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940038/dipp) for the link)

P.P.S: Wanted to make this list for a long time already.

Thnx [@zlgdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3008340/zlgdev), [@Kyone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223102/kyone), [@MinosL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571949/minosl) for updates

Comment: Being an absolute newbie in Android development, I don't understand No 3. What do you mean 'Release certificate'?

Comment: @papadi then you should read this carefully (there are some pitfalls): http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Don't forget to make sure the account you're using to test IAB is **opted-in as a tester** using the "opt-in URL" generated once you've uploaded a build; AND that it's **linked to a valid payment method**.

Comment: After adding BILLING permission to main manifest file, this error dialog box removed from my build. But I don't know why before I can able to add In App Products into play store account!!!

Comment: on android studio: build -> generate signed APK, then install to device

Comment: Shouldn't it be easier to just *test* IAP? Or to test things in general..

Comment: The keys for me: first, what @Kyone said about the tester needing to opt in and to have a valid payment method set up; second, that the APK is signed with the release certificate - by default a debug build uses a debug keystore, and in VS you need to manually edit the .csproj file to tell it to use your release keystore instead, as documented [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/visual-studio-xa-4.2.5-and-earlier) in the "Permanently Use a Different Keystore" section.

Comment: also worth noting; test account should not be linked to developer account (should not have access to upload APK)

Comment: also worth noting; if "App signing certificate" is enabled, then we cannot use our local APK to test with real purchases since we cannot sign with signing certificate. (took me like 3 hours to find out)

Comment: This is funny, I have one app where I can do how many purchases I want in debug mode, with different version code from the one uploaded.How is it possible? I also think I'm not in the tester list

Comment: Wait for 24hrs after uploading it on google playstore and to test on debug apk right away use this SKU 'android.test.purchased'

Comment: I've been successfully testing with 1) a **signed debug app** that is 2) **not the main account on the device**, so the process for Google IAB testing seems to be not as strict as noted above.

Comment: @MinosL 1) Signed debug app is ok and it's mentioned in the answer. 2) "Main account is not nessesary" -  thanks, longilong added it to the list

Comment: No need for the messing with debuggable keystores. I was able to 'debug' my app through logs using `adb logcat`.

Comment: Quick note from my side, as this bordered me a while:
On the dev docs Google says that you can do local builds after the first alpha/beta roll out was successfully. This isn't working for me. After doing all the stuff up there, I only managed to make it work with the downloaded version from the Play Store, NOT A LOCAL BUILD (even if same signing, release build and installed from sdcard).

Maybe it's my fault, but just wanted to mention it here.

Comment: Regarding step 3 of Prerequisites: If "App Signing by Google Play" is enabled then how can I debug and impement the code. It will require me to upload new APK every time I make any changes.

Comment: Emphasis for the line "Must be the main account"!

Comment: AndroidManifest must include "com.android.vending.BILLING" permission.
This worked for me... thanks man!

Comment: Last note was most helpful. If you linked Service Account after you added products (which is usually true), you need to make any changes in price of the product, then it will work. Also, make sure you see linked Service Account in Google Play Console (in linked product). if you don't you have re-create your Service Account and indicate PERMISSIONS in step 2 (I just granted full access)

Comment: i have all above still i'm getting same error

Comment: The information here is outdated in 2021. Please check `dor506` and `Pablo Cegarra` answers

Comment: It is working correctly if I add licensed testers but doesn't work without the licensed testers. How can I be sure that everything is gonna work fine when the app is published?

Comment: @Donki google purposely did this you can check for more details https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

Comment: Thank you. For me the issue was that the test APK had a different versionCode to the APK on Google Play.

Answer (score 148):

The same will happen if your published version is not the same as the version you're testing on your phone.

For example, uploaded version is `android:versionCode="1"`, and the version you're testing on your phone is `android:versionCode="2"`

Comment: can u tell please me what if uploaded version is `android:versionCode="1"` and phone is `android:versionCode="2"` dose it ok or i have to change my apk google play ?.

Comment: What you need to do is to bump down the local version to "1" so it matches the current live version, as least temporarily for testing.

Comment: Looks like there are 2 common fixes to this error depending on your situation.  In my case it was this one.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue. Was debugging fine with release signed apk on my attached device. Then, changed the versioncode and it started getting the 1005 error. whew!

Comment: @Anna be aware that -1005 is also USER_CANCELLED if you use iabHelper

Comment: This does not happen anymore apparently https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/51#issuecomment-305373866

Answer (score 106):

In the old developer console:

`Settings` -> `Account details` -> `License Testing` -> Gmail accounts with testing access and type here your accounts

In new developer console:

`Setup` -> `License Testing` -> Type your Gmail account, hit 'Enter' and click 'Save'.

[image: Google Play License testing]

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: Hi my email is added in the license account. Still i am getting the error

Comment: Special attention to the `hit 'Enter'` part. I was just clicking save and the emails were not being added to the list.

Comment: I can't ever repay you enough for saving my life, my marriage, and my sanity with this answer. Bless you.

Comment: This also works for me, but I have one concern. How can I be sure that this will work when the app is published?

Comment: This did it for me

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 48):

You need to sign your APK with your live certificate. Then install that onto your test device. You can then test InAppBilling. If you are testing your application by direct run via eclipse to device(In debug mode) then you will get this error.

If you are using `android.test.purchased` as the SKU, it will work all the way, but you won't have the developerPayload in your final response.

If you are using your own draft in app item you can test all the way but you will be charged and so will have to refund it yourself afterwards.

You cannot buy items with the same gmail account that you use for the google play development console.

Comment: +1 Running from debugger uses debug certificate.  After exporting the app and creating a new public key (and installing it in the developer console), just email yourself the apk and install it from your gmail inbox.

Comment: If I want to try "android.test.purchased" am I then going to change the SKU in both my code and in the developer console?

Answer (score 45):

**Conclusions in 2021**

For all of you who concerned about debugging - You **CAN** run and debug and test the code in debug mode

Here's how you can test the process:

(This of course relies on the fact that you have already added and activated your products, and your code is ready for integration with those products)

1. Add **com.android.vending.BILLING** to the manifest
2. Upload **signed apk** to internal testing
3. Add **license testers** (P**lay console -> Settings -> License testing**) - If you use multiple accounts on your device and you're not sure which one to use, just add all of them as testers.
4. Run the application, as you normally would, from Android Studio (* The application should have the same version code as the one you just uploaded to internal testing)

I did the above and it is working just fine.

Comment: I can't ever repay you enough for saving my life, my marriage, and my sanity with this answer. Bless you.

Comment: Worked for me too. I was able to test in app purchase in my flutter app using an emulator. (i am using in_app_purchase library in flutter)

Comment: don't forget to add com.android.vending.BILLING to your debug/AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I skipped step 1 and it is working for testing purposes. I did that on behalf this article https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate?authuser=1#remove

Comment: Beautiful, worked for me! Very nice solution.

Comment: It is still beyond me why Google added support for sideloading & debug builds, but still **forces the versionCode to match**  the build uploaded to GPlay store. It's also not mentioned in the docs (at least not anymore). 

But then again, we also still can't reset subscription trials and need to recreate Google accounts each time, so there's that too. 

I hope someone at Google reads this and makes our life easier.

Comment: There is no need for the first step (adding the permission). Because it's added in the billing library. It's already declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file of the com.android.billingclient:billing library.

Comment: what worked for me was step # 3, but it's no longer `Settings`, it's `Setup`, as in: `Play console` -> `Setup` -> `License testing`.

Answer (score 22):

If you're here from 2018, you need to download the APK directly from Play Store and install the "derived" APK. Maybe it is because of Google's Play Store has a feature "App Signing by Google Play".

### Update:

Still a possible solution in the year 2023.

Comment: Which APK? I am using AIDL do i still need to do that?

Comment: @ZhenLiu I guess not needed

Comment: In addition, the app cannot be already installed on the device by a different means (ie. Android Studio). Installation/update from the Play Store will work, but the IAP will not - you'll get the OPs error.

Comment: How do we debug this?

Comment: I recently started getting this error, I also recently removed this stuff from my google app store settings thinking it wasn't needed. It is indeed needed. I must have added these settings years & years ago and forgot why.

Comment: Cool! I guess I have to update this answer 5 years later.

Answer (score 12):

This is tested for debug/release builds & either if the app is signed by Play Signing (which means the signing certificate of the delivered app from Google Play is different from the certificate when installing the app from your machine using Android Studio).

**check these following steps:**

1. Create your product on Google Play Console and activate it.
2. Add license testers (open the **Google Play Console -> Settings -> License Testing**). Add all the Google accounts listed on your android device.
3. Upload signed app to the internal testing track (it must be in release mode).
4. Use the testing link to check if the app is available to download (make sure the uploaded app version to the internal track matches the version you're testing in debug mode). It takes some time to see the latest uploaded version there, so I recommend clearing the cache of the Play Store app.
5. Run your app in debug mode from Android Studio. (Again, the app version and build number must match the values on the published version to the internal track).

I tested that on two different Google Play Console accounts (two different apps), and it works.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you still get the error after adding License Testing. Thank you!

Comment: Tested today, internal track build worked great!

Answer (score 4):

This will happen if you use a different version of the apk than the one in the google play.

Comment: there is no such thing any longer not sure if it was in 2013,

Answer (score 4):

Let me just add what happened with me, may help some one.

It was mainly due to signing.

Since I have added the signing details in the Project structure, I was thinking that every time when I run, expected signed apk is getting installed. But build type 'debug' was selected.

Below fix solved the problem for me.

- Generated signed apk of build type 'release'.
- Manually installed the apk.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to many answers and comments on SO and other sites, you do NOT have to perform preliminary tests with an alpha/beta version of your product that has been downloaded from Google Play onto your test device (the alpha/beta publication process often eats up half a day).  Neither do you have to load and re-load a signed release apk from your developer studio to your test device.

You CAN debug preliminary Google Play in app billing services using the debug app as loaded from your developer studio directly to your test device via ADB.  If you are experiencing errors that prevent this, likely you have done something wrong in your code.  Pay especially close attention to the CASE of your SKU's (product ids) and their format (for example, if you load your APK as com.mydomain.my_product_id, be sure your try to purchase it this way - providing the same case and domain).  Also, pay especially close attention to your itemType - this should be either "inapp" or "subs" for managed/unmanaged in app purchases or subscriptions, respectively.

As suggested by Chirag Patel, provided you have your billing code properly established, perform all testing using the android.test.purchased Sku (product ID) during your preliminary tests.  Check for this ID throughout your billing operations to pass it through signature, token and payload checks, since this data is not provided by the Google test system.  Additionally, give one of your test products this ID to test its purchase, unlock/load and presentation all the way through your schema.  To CLEAR the purchase, simply consume it, passing the same Sku AND a token string formatted this way - no other fields are relevant :

```
    "inapp:"+appContext.getAppContext().getPackageName()+":android.test.purchased";
```

Once you have completed this phase of testing, move to semi-live testing with your alpha/beta product.  Create a Google group (essentially a mailing list), add your test users emails to it, and add/invite this group to test your device in this phase (performed at the "APK" portion of your app's Google developer listing).  Purchases will be simulated but not actually charged - however to clear and re-test the purchases, Google indicates that you must refund them from your Google wallet.  THIS is the only phase of testing that requires the time-consuming process of using alpha/beta loads and test users.

Answer (score 3):

The trick for me was realizing that the License Tester email I added to Google Play Console needs to match the email address that's associated with the device, which is found in the device Settings app under "About Phone -> Google Account".

The email addresses under "Settings -> Google" and in the Play Store app don't count, and can even be different than the email address associated to the device, which apparently can only be changed by factory reset.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I saw the same message due to the different signatures of the installed apk and an uploaded to the market apk.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, and it was not solved before i read the post from DZDomi. It suddenly occurred to be that there is a setting in the Google Developer Console  that you need to enable. In the "In app purchases" section, there's a line for your product and to the far right there's a status for it. It should be ACTIVE!

Answer (score 2):

**2023**

In my case

i just update the `compileSdkVersion = 31 to compileSdkVersion = 33  and targetSdkVersion = 31 to targetSdkVersion = 33`

```
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
```

Because the latest version of **Android is 13**

Before the upgradation, I received this

[image]

then perfectly it worked fine

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this issue for days, I had attempted to **deploy to play console** and test on my phone again and again.

i had 2 test phones and there were 2 different main accounts but i forgot what is the main account is so if you have more than 1 account sign in to your Google Play. make sure you have added your main account to the testers list on google app console

**you can also try to add all of the accounts to make sure that the issue is not related to different google accounts.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug IAB what do you have to do is:

1. Submit to google play a version of your app with the IAB permission on the manifest:
2. Add a product to your app on google play: [Administering In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html)
3. Set a custom debug keystore signed: [Configure Eclipse to use signed keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886814/configure-eclipse-to-use-signed-keystore)

Answer (score 1):

Another reason not mentioned here is that you need to be testing on a real device. 
With the emulator becoming really good, it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

*Recently google has implemented a change on their systems, and since you have uploaded at least one APK to your console, you can test your in-app requests with your app with any version code / number.*

Cross reference [LINK](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/51)

> Configure [`gradle`](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#gradle-sign) to sign your debug build for debugging.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.jks")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "my-alias"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

Just hold on a while after uploading your app on play store because google takes some time to update app versions.It will work !

Comment: It was hard, but indeed. Waiting for 8 hours fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to integrate with another app that is not published but has the same id, version code, and version name of deployed one so don't forget to edit appname.iml file version in flutter app because I stuck on to it with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i tried to check it with the debug.keystore , i mean running it through eclipse.I exported it with the keystore with which i published in alpha mode(it must be published before you can test it).installed it in my phone and than i could test it normally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem also occurs, when you have added an in-app purchase after you uploaded the apk, but you have not published the application in the play store (alpha, beta and production).

Which basically means, that you have to add the In-App purchase AFTER you have published the apk in the Play store (alpha, beta and production). Otherwise you wont be able to purchase or query for the In-App purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when installing on the device directly from the IDE (debug or release mode - doesn't matter).

But when I **put the app on the Google Play marketplace, and then installed the app from this marketplace on the same phone** (previously uninstalling the "ad hoc" version intalled directly on the device from the IDE), **and IAP started working**.

But when I debug AFTER installation, I get the signing key mismatch, have to uninstall the app from the phone, then debug works, but IAP doesn't work again... Frustrating, but you have to have installed the app from the marketplace as it turns out.

Comment: Did you find  any solution as its hectic to upload the build on closed testing everytime for development ?

Comment: The IAP product doesn't work when building the app from the Visual Studio. It works only when I install the app from the google play marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

- **You cannot buy in-app items for your own app.** (try with different Gmail account)
- That email add to Licence testing `(Playconsole > Setup > Licence testing)`
- Also add `com.android.vending.BILLING` to the manifest and upload app for internal testing or production

Answer (score -1):

All answers are valid according to their situation, but my case was different of all. I'm using revenuecat and some configuration was wrong.

- I didn't enable google playstore developer api for the current project in cloud developer console
- then make sure you've linked right project with in API access tab. (In my case, I was unable to link my actual project until I enabled playstore developer
- Provide right permissions to revenuecat email according to documentation and invite user.

It will then take 36 hours to enable revenuecat API for this project.

Answer (score -2):

If all the settings are OK and still you are getting the error `This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information.`

Edit your In-App Products pricing in the Play Store or deactivate and activate the In-App products. This will solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).