# This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla)

I already have an application (with inapp purchase) in android market. My problem is inapp purchase functionality is not working properly and I re-write the code again. Now I want to run the application to test but i getting error message. 
"This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play."

I have permission in manifest file too. And checked with signed apk.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I already searched. I didnt found any solution that why i am asking..

Comment: @Monali If my answer is helping you then please accept it so it will help others also.

Comment: i was facing similar issue.. but not on all users.. only some users may be county specific , any way to fix this? i was used billing v6 version

Answer (score 3):

you have to sign the apk and uninstall previous apk and re-install the sign apk in device..then this error will not occur....Try it..

Comment: I followed the suggestion, but still getting same message even with the signed apk, I tested thrice.

Comment: In IABHelper, I initialized ITEM_TYPE_INAPP as public static final String ITEM_TYPE_INAPP = "subs"; Initially it was "inapp" instead of subs. Is that what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are install unsigned apk on android device then this `"This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play"` error is displaying so First uninstall old app from device and re-install new signed apk on device, it will solve your problem.

Comment: tried with signed apk also..still showing same error message.

Comment: Do we need same keystore for signed apk which was at market? I have created new keystore.

Comment: @Monali yes, Same keystore is required.

Comment: @Dipak: it even doesn't work with the same keystore.