# android in-app this version of application is not configer for billing through Google play

Tags: android, in-app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla)
>   [This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716750/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla)

i upload my apk to `Draft` (last night 10:00pm) and some in-app products() and now i try to test it but it display this error `this version of application is not configer for billing through   Google play .` i already check the `android:versionCode` of apk are same .
then what may the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are install unsigned apk on android device then this `"This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play"` error is displaying so First uninstall old app from device and re-install new signed apk on device, it will solve your problem.

And See below link for more information.

[This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla)