# "This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play" error with signed apk (billing v3)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla) describe relatively same problem. But my problem seems unique in these points,

1. My apk is signed.
2. App was upload a week ago.
3. Purchase items was created a week ago.
4. I'm using a listed account for testing.
5. In app version 3.

The only confusing point is that KeyStore generated from a different device using Eclipse, I'm using Android Studio here.

The problem leaves no clue except above point. Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Android Studio or eclipse does not make an different for signature if using on same device/machine as keystore contains the machine address not the eclispe/android studio address so the only difference is if your are on diffrent device and signing from that machine that make sense and that cause issue

Comment: @UsmanKurd Thanks man.Problem solved.
It occurred for the different machine.