# Application not configured for billing through Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on an android project and I am trying to implement In App Billing V3.

I have uploaded my app to Google Play, and add an IAP to the app. I can successfully retrieve a list of the IAP my app has along with its price but when I actually try to make a purchase my device gets the following error (there is no error in

> This version of the application is not configured for billing through
>   Google Play. Check the help centre for more information.

Below is the code that retrieves the IAP's available and does the purchase

```
ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
        skuList.add("mysqlmanager_pro");

        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
        try
        {
            Bundle skuDetail = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
            Log.d("Billing", "Response Received");

            int billingResponse = skuDetail.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
            if (billingResponse == 0)
            {
                //Get list of IAP's to purcase - NOT NEEDED
                ArrayList responseList = skuDetail.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                Log.d("Billing", "Response");

                Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), 
                        "mysqlmanager_pro", "inapp", "");

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

                startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 
                        Defines.IntentRequestCodes.IAP_PURCHASE_REQUEST, new Intent(), 
                        Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                /*for (String thisResponse : responseList)
                {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                    String sku = object.getString("productid");
                    String price = object.getString("price");
                }*/
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Billing", ex.toString());
        }
```

My onCreate contains the following

```
mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mService = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            }
        };

        bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), 
                mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Below is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.Agreement"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewDBConnection"
            android:label="@string/new_mysql_connection">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ConnectionManager"
            android:label="@string/connection_manager">
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditDBConnections"
            android:label="@string/edit_database_connections">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ServerStatus"
            android:label="Server Status">
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ConnectionManager"/>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".ConnectedDBManagerHost"
            android:label="Connected to DB">
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="BillingReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: To test your app using real skus you must have the same APK you uploaded to the Google Play, i.e., an apk signed with the same certificate

Comment: It will work when you run on release signed .apk or install form google play console

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here:

1. After uploading your apk to Google Play, you need to wait a while
   for Google's servers to update (similar to when you publish an
   update). This can take an hour or two or longer in my experience. So
   try again in a few hours.
2. Ensure that the version of the apk you uploaded is configured for
   IAP (through the permissions), and then only test IAP with a signed
   apk. That is, export and sign your apk from Eclipse and then install
   locally onto your device. Otherwise, if you run an unsigned version
   of the application directly from the IDE, it will not work and
   you'll see an error.

   Note: You don't need to upload a new apk every time you make minor changes, as long as the currently uploaded draft apk was configured with the correct permissions and you published your IAP items on the dev console. The only annoying part is that you have to export and sign your application each time after making changes and run it on a device locally.
3. Check that the versionCode of your uploaded apk has the same
   versionCode as your local version of the apk.
4. You can not use your developer account to make test purchases,
   because Google Wallet doesn't allow you to purchase items from
   yourself. So you need to set up some test accounts on the Developer
   Console and try purchasing items from a device running the test
   account.

Comment: Thanks, I was stumped for a while, and point 3 above was the issue! Seems that I'll need to bump the versionCode up, submit new APK, and then to keep testing bring the version code back down for a few hours until Google Play backend processes the new APK!

Comment: The line: `Check that the versionCode of your uploaded apk has the same versionCode as your local version of the apk.` was very helpful for me.

Comment: Should the submitted apk be published or I can keep it as draft in prod?

Comment: NEEDS TO RUN WITH MANUAL INSTALL BY COPYING INTO SDCARD

Comment: I've been fighting with similar, but not exactly the same issues.  There's another question with useful answers at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla

Comment: So every time I make a change I need to build and generate a signed apk, then use ADB to install the signed apk?

Comment: Apparently no need to be the same `versionCode` anymore https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/51#issuecomment-305373866