# After App Signing - IAP not working

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-app-signing, app-signing

As per latest Google Play Store, we have enroll our applications into App Signing.
After this enrollment our IAP product is not working and showing error as :

"This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play".

**WE HAVE ALREADY UPLOADED NEW BUILDS FOR ALPHA RELEASE.**

Still, we are getting this error.

Also we have checked that if we sign an APK with older keystore.

We are able to see the IAP dialog correctly.

Please suggest.

Comment: There are a lot of questions on the same topic, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692402/application-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-play). Have you read through all of them before posting this?

Comment: I have checked this, I am getting error after enrolling for App Signing program.

Comment: Google App Signing should not change anything, because the APK will be signed the with the release key by Google Play Store servers. Are you sure you didn't mess up something with the upload key?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this,

1. If you create sign APK from new keystore.
2. And tried installing new APK rather than Play Store.
3. Then IAP will not work.

***Previously this is working as expected.***

Also installing new APK from anywhere else. You are not able to test Application upgrade scenarios.

That means if you have previously released app from old Sign APK then you enroll into App Signing and test upgrade scenarios from APK which has been uploaded on your private server, then your application will not install on the device.

**The solution for this is to each time you want to test above scenarios, you should have to upload sign APKs to Play Store (Alpha).**