# In app billing on Android problems

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have some problems with in app billing.
I have an inapp product on my app. I have uploaded the apk as alpha on the developer console, created the alpha Google group and subscribed some account (not my account) to this group. With one of these accounts, I have downloaded from play store the alpha version but when I try to buy the inapp product an error message appears.

> this version of application is not configured for billing through google play

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla

Answer (score 0):

it is will be happen, if your published version is not the same as the version you're testing on your phone.

For example, 
uploaded version is `android:versionCode="1"`, and the version you're testing on your phone is `android:versionCode="2"`

Some other reason it also happen

```
   1. Google takes a while to process applications and update them to their servers, for me it takes about half a day. So after publish the apk in Google Play, you must wait a few hours before the in-app products will respond normally and allow for regular purchases.

  2. Export and sign APK. Unsigned APK trying to make purchases will get error.
```

Comment: As I said, the app is already published, in the alpha channel.

Comment: And I'm testing the app downloaded from the play store, from the alpha channel