# Android in-app products

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have an app on google play and I want to make a new version with in-app billing. I have uploaded a beta .apk which requires the

> android.permission.BILLING.

On Google Developer Console there is an In-app Products function. But when I click on it, it is complaining:

> "To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to
>   your APK."

Why? My beta .apk already has the BILLING permission, it shouldn't complain about it.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11076056/4896787) is the error you're encountering?

Comment: I have uploaded the beta .apk many hours ago (5-7). Maybe I have to wait more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right permission to add is not android.permission.BILLING, but com.android.vending.BILLING.