# Google Play In-app billing V3 - Error - Authentication is Required

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, payment, in-app-billing

I have looked at other similar questions on SO regarding the same issue and all point to the same point. To check the ID of the product. I am implementing in-app purchases for the first time and i think i am using the correct product id in the code. I am following TrivialDrive sample.

So, the error is as follows:

[image]

My product id from Google Play:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
package com.xx.xxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.xx.xxx.util.IabHelper;
import com.xx.xxx.util.IabResult;
import com.xx.xxx.util.Inventory;
import com.xx.xxx.util.Purchase;

public class UpgradeDonateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String base64EncodedPublicKey = "PUBLIC_KEY_REPLACED";
    private static final int PURCHASE_RESPONSE = 1;
    private static final String PURCHASE_TOKEN = "purchase_token";


    private static final String SKU_UPGRADE_2 = "test";
    //private static final String SKU_UPGRADE = "Upgrade";
    private static final String SKU_DONATE_10 = "donate_10";
    private static final String SKU_DONATE_5 = "donate_5";
    private static final String SKU_DONATE_3 = "donate_3";
    private static final String SKU_DONATE_2 = "donate_2";

    private boolean mIsUpgraded = false;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView title;

    private IabHelper mIabHelper;
    private Button btnUpgrade;


    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener
            = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {

            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Query inventory finished");

            if (mIabHelper == null) return;

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle failure
                Toast.makeText(UpgradeDonateActivity.this, "onQueryInventoryFinished Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Query inventory successful");

            Purchase upgradePurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_UPGRADE_2);
            mIsUpgraded = (upgradePurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(upgradePurchase));
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "User is " + (mIsUpgraded ? "Upgraded" : "Not Upgraded"));
        }
    };


    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
        return true;
    }


    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase) {


            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

            if(mIabHelper == null) return;

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle error
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Error Purchasing: "+result);
                return;
            }

            if(!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
                return;
            }

            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Purchase successful.");

            if(purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_UPGRADE_2)) {
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Purchase is upgrade. Congratulating user.");
                mIsUpgraded = true;
            }

        }
    };


    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
            new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                              IabResult result) {

                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        //clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                        Toast.makeText(UpgradeDonateActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // handle error
                        Toast.makeText(UpgradeDonateActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upgrade_donate);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        title.setText("");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        btnUpgrade = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_upgrade);
        btnUpgrade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mIabHelper = new IabHelper(UpgradeDonateActivity.this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
                mIabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "In-app Billing setup Failed");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "In-app Billing setup OK");
                            Toast.makeText(UpgradeDonateActivity.this, "In-app Billing setup OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            mIabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(UpgradeDonateActivity.this, SKU_UPGRADE_2, PURCHASE_RESPONSE, mPurchaseFinishedListener, PURCHASE_TOKEN);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
        if (mIabHelper == null) return;

        // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
        if (!mIabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
            // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
            // billing...
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else {
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
        }
    }


    public void consumeItem() {
        mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mIabHelper != null) mIabHelper.dispose();
        mIabHelper = null;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is it that i am doing wrong in this case? How should i fix it?

Comment: are you logged on the device using your google account

Comment: yes.. i checked and re-checked it. I am logged in, with the tester account i mentioned in the playstore.

Comment: I hope tester account is not the same as the account that is being used for developer console.

Comment: nope.. both are different..

Comment: have you accepted being a tester for the app on a separate webpage having link similer to https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.example.trivialdrivesample

Comment: I didn't get any confirmation email as such, when i added the tester account. But, i am logged in on the device, with the tester account. How do i send a confirmation email for the tester account? I added the tester in closed alpha testing, not in beta testing.

Comment: on upload APK page in ALPHA TESTING there is a link "Opt-in URL ". Go there and accept being a tester using the testing account

Comment: @meghraj27, i think i understand what i doing wrong now, will get back to you, thanks for your time.

Comment: Ivan is correct, I thought you did that part. Just fill in some dummy values, content rating questionnaire and upload some dummy graphics as specified.

Comment: here is a checklist http://stackoverflow.com/a/22469253/1819570

Comment: @meghraj27, please add your final comment as an answer. Will up vote it. Since Ivan "found" my issue, i will accept his answer.

Comment: which one, the comment about "opt-in url" or about checklist?

Comment: I think you can post both in the same answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your .apk with billing in place (and right permissions) is *Published* (be it alpha) and allow some time for Google Play to absorb the new .apk, may be a couple of hours.

Also, make sure the application version code in your current development build is the same as the one of the published billing-enabled build.

Comment: I am little confused here.. How can i publish apk for Alpha testing. I mean, i uploaded the signed build in Alpha Testing section and it says, "Draft in Alpha" now. I have options to "Promote to Beta" and "promote to prod". Should i say "promote to prod" and save it?

Comment: You have to publish the app, long as it's in `Draft`, Play Services will not even consider it. Look for the Publish button in the dev console and don't worry, builds are not magically promoted from alpha to prod, after you publish it, no one except people in alpha will be able to see it.

Comment: No problem, that's somewhat of a tricky part, because documentation kinda gives you the feeling everything can be done in `Draft` -- mostly true, except for testing billing :)

Answer (score 1):

On upload APK page in ALPHA TESTING there is a link "Opt-in URL ". Go there and accept being a tester using the testing account.
Aso, here is a useful checklist https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469253/1819570