# this version of the application is not configured for billing through google play?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I tried to first implement in my app billing. I have try this library https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 and followed the procedures> https://blahti.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/how-to-add-in-app-billing-in-android-part-1/, but I get the response :

> "this version of the application is not configured for billing through
>   google play"

Here's what I have done:

1. upload apk in alpha testing with version code: "1" and name version 
   "1.0.0"
2. defining the in-app products (status active)
3. trying to make a purchase through an application that I installed on my android device studio. With version code: "1" and name version
   "1.0.0"

so how to fix it ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla