# Android in-app billing error with android.test.purchased item

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to test my in app purchase flow with the fake item android.test.purchased, from android documentation. I'm not able to test this flow, just when I launch it, I get this error: "The item you requested is not available for purchase". I have the  permission in my manifest and I don't understand why I get this error with the fake item android.test.purchased.

Comment: having the same issue, It was working just fine for me yesterday, I setup the server side validation and wanted to test. ran into problems with my product IDs so i checked the static ones again and they gave the same errors.

Comment: Any solution? I am also using static productId to test, but always get `Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/ees/acquire` and `df-dferh-01` errors. Searching hours now, but all useless info only.

Comment: **In my case:** I consume purchased item and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the list of requirements for the Google IAB testing.

**Prerequisites:**

1. AndroidManifest must include "com.android.vending.BILLING"
   permission.
2. APK is built in release mode.
3. APK is signed with the release certificate(s).
4. APK is uploaded to alpha/beta distribution channel (previously - as
   a draft) to the developer console at least once. (takes some time
   ~2h-24h).
5. IAB products are published and their status set to active.
6. Test account(s) is added in developer console.

**Testing requirements:**

1. Test APK has the same versionCode as the one uploaded to developer
   console.
2. Test APK is signed with the same certificate(s) as the one uploaded
   to dev.console.
3. Test account (not developer) - is the main account on the device.
4. Test account is opted-in as a tester and it's linked to a valid
   payment method.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla).

Comment: I know this requisites and I don't buying any production/test items, I'm using google play static responses: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static

Comment: Did you sign your apk file?

Comment: You don't need to sign your apk file to test static responses.

Comment: Okay, are you running app on real device?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have updated my question with the new error message I get after increase the versionCode.

Comment: Just try to sign your apk, I almost sure problem is in it.

Comment: You don't need to do any of these if you test static responses

Answer (score 0):

To test in-app products or make in-app purchases in your alpha or beta channel app, each tester needs to opt-in to your app’s alpha or beta test. On your test’s opt-in URL, your testers will get an explanation of what it means to be a tester and a link to opt-in.

The most current version of the Google Play application must be installed on the device.

Ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469253/3758024

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11076056/3758024

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: I am not doing any alpha or beta app purchase, I'm using in app static responses: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static

Comment: You have to publish your app to Alpha environment to test In-App Purchases

Comment: I know, and I have already done it. But static responses doesn't  require to publish the app in alpha nor beta channel.

Comment: 'versionCode' of your current apk need to be <= 'versionCode' of published apk.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked it and after change that, I get another error ("the item you requested is not available for purchase"). It's very strange because it's a fake item and it's suppossed to be always available. I'll investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem and fixed listing the "android.test.purchased" ID in the IAP activate list.
I know Google says that you do not need to list the IAP ID with static responses but, in my case, after I listed the ID "android.test.purchase" and activated I get success in my tests