# Flutter In App Purchase call does not return on Android

Tags: flutter

(on Android) In my code when I want to start fetching products IDs the code never goes past this line:

```
final bool isAvailable = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();
```

And sometimes randomly it executes that line and stops here:

```
    try {
      ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(_productIds.toSet());
      //...
    } on PlatformException catch (platformException) {
      print(platformException);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
```

I've put both lines in a try-catch error but no error nor exception. I am clueless at this point.

I'm using `in_app_purchase: ^2.0.0` and `Flutter 2.5.3 stable channel`

I'd appreciate if you have any hint.

*P.S. everything works fine on iOS*

Comment: check ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56581534/flutter-not-finding-any-products-for-in-app-purchases

Comment: @AwiasRehman it's not that, it does not execute the line, that's the problem.

Comment: I recently had a dev with a similar problem and it was caused by including the android payments library in their build.gradle file.

Comment: @developerextraordinare what do you mean? i'm putting what the documentation says `implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:$billing_version"`

Comment: `Note: It is not necessary to depend on com.android.billingclient:billing in your own app's android/app/build.gradle file. If you choose to do so know that conflicts might occur.` Taken from https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

Comment: Removing it did't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have the answer:
Removing `flutter_inapp_purchase` package fixed it! I guess there should have been a warning at least!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Removing the billing client implementation from the app-level build.gradle solved it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70589769/13199543) for details.