# flutter in_app_pruchase - consumables Billing library version 4.0+ is required

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, flutter-in-app-purchase

I'm trying out the in_app_purchase, and everything works so far (even with test license and test buy), except consumables.

When I try to mark the IAP as consumable, then the developer console tells me the following:

> "Billing library version 4.0+ is required to use this feature"

I've declared in pubspec.yaml dependencies

`in_app_purchase: ^3.0.7`

and also tested `^3.0.6`

I've also set up `android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` with the following code snippets:

```
...
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
...
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version"
            android:value="5.0.0" />
...
```

I'm only using internal testing track.

What might be the possible reasons?

1. Is it an merchant account problem?
2. Might it be a play console problem?
3. Did I forgot something in my project?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Similar (not exactly duplicate) question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla?rq=1

Comment: `in_app_purchase` is using `Google Play Billing Library 3.0` for now and there is an open issue on github about this. issue link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107370

Comment: Same error `We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 4 or newer to publish this app.` in my Google Play Console.Any workaround for this now?

Comment: A user on github has apparently fixed the issue by updating the plugin and invalidating the gradle cache. Here is [his comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107370#issuecomment-1242648875)

Comment: you can modify library by your self clone repository and add to your project as module and use after changes you want

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Here is what worked for me:

- remove `pubspec.lock`
- run `flutter pub get`

Reason why this worked:

`in_app_purchase` has a dependecy `in_app_purchase_android` which was locked in my `pubspec.lock` to a version that was still using **Google Play Billing Library 3.0**. Removing `pubspec.lock` and running `flutter pub get` fetched the latest version of `in_app_purchase_android` which uses **Google Play Billing Library 5.0**.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Google Play Billing Library dependency to your app's build.gradle file as shown:

```
dependencies {
    val billing_version = "5.0.0"

    implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version")
}
```