# Google Play game services - Android samples errors

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games

Based on Android docs (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#before_you_begin) for learning how to configure Google Play game APIs onto a sample app such as TypeANumber, I was wondering why I get the following resource errors from the BaseGameUtils library after importing the project, BasicSamples, from their GitHub's (https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) source files:

[image]

... Based on the directory in the left panel, did I import it properly? All I did was import it straight from the directory: android-basic-samples/BasicSamples/build.gradle as stated in Step 1 of the link.

Here's my (untouched) Gradle file for the library, BaseGameUtils:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
        ext.appcompat_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
        ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
        ext.gms_library_version = '8.1.0'
    }

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:${gms_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${gms_library_version}"
}

android {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_compile_version')) {
        ext.android_compile_version = 23
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_version')) {
        ext.android_version = '23'
    }

    compileSdkVersion android_compile_version
    buildToolsVersion android_version
}
```

... Did anyone else experience this issue before?

**EDIT AS OF 4/7, 3:37PM:**

So I ended up importing the project again, but within the AndroidStudioProjects directory this time (does that really make a difference?) and I actually ended up making some progress since then. However, for part 3 under step 1 within the docs:

[image]

... I ended up changing not only the package name in TypeANumber's manifest file, but also the package directory along with the classes in it as follows:

[image]

... So my question now is, am I on the right track so far in terms of the navigation directory panel at the left? :)

Comment: Hi did you ever get this working? I'm getting some similar errors after trying to install the samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The [package attribute in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) should always match the directories. Plain and simple. That's why changing it would require you to do a complete refactor. Just keep on going with the tutorial accordingly and I think you'll be good.