# force eclipse to sign android apk with public key

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, osx-mountain-lion

I need to test in-app billing. But having to explicitly sign with the public key each time takes long. Is there a way to get eclipse to use the public key each time (when I click the green run button)? If it's a complicated process, please give a step by step instruction. I am using Mac (latest, with retina display).

Answer (score 0):

Open the Window Menu -> Preferences -> Android -> Build

On the field "Custom debug keystore" select your public key

Comment: When I do I get the message `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`. I know the key is correct. Where do I enter the password? There is no password field, yet when I export the apk I always have to use a password.

Comment: You should use two different keys, one for development and another one for release. I usually register the android default key (debug.keystore password android).

Comment: [You can use the same key for both development and release](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10886814/1134080) (but don't do it if key security is important to you). The copy of your key for development should be aliased `androiddebugkey`, and both the keystore and key passwords need to be `android`. Otherwise you will get the error message.