# jar mismatch from log cat on program run using google play service

Tags: android, android-logcat

[image: logcat]
im following a tutorial and i have encounter a couple of problem doing [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) tutorial from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682025/generate-keytool-sha-1/22683385#22683385) and now this problem what seem to be the problem. i was able to generate the sha1 now and i have imported the google play service lib but now i have encountered this problem how did i come up with this and how do i fix this

**UPDATE**
[image]
i have this on my SDK
**UPDATE**
support folder looks like this [image]

Comment: Similar to these question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045568/jar-mismatch-found-2-versions-of-android-support-v4-jar-in-the-dependency-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar mismatch is due to different version of the support library.

You can copy the `android-support-v4/jar` from `sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar` to the libs folder of both Google play services library project and your Android project.

Make sure you have the updated Support Library.

You can check **Adding Support Libraries without Resources** @

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Edit: The latest is rev 19.0.1 as shown in the below snap shot

To download

[image]

Edit :

Do you see this under `sdk/extras/android/support` . Then open v4 and copy the jars to both libs folder

[image]

Comment: i have only android-support-v7-appcompat is this the one?found it here ..\android-sdk_r22.2-windows\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support

Comment: @HakHak download the latest support library from the android sdk manager and this `android-support-v4/jar` can be found at `sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`. Check https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: UPDATED the question i did what you told me but still the error is there do you think i just need to delete the whole sdk and download it again?

Comment: @HakHak no need for that

Comment: @HakHak do you see the second snap in my post?? Do you have the jar under the mentioned folder??

Comment: but the error is there @integer/google_play_services_version is there and it says No resource found that matches the given name. and the error is cause the lib is not matching and i did what you told me they just wont match

Comment: @HakHak it will if you do it right. While this is a different issue altogether. `@integer/google_play_services_version`. You need to have upodated google play services and you need to have version number mentioned in the meta-tag under application tag of manifest

Comment: that is weird i have a folder that is named "m2repository" and found it there "android-sdk_r22.2-windows\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7" should i move it there?in support because they are the same

Comment: @HakHak i don't know what your talking about nor does the docs mention what you just commented. Follow the metioned steps in my post and it will work and i am sure about that and also copy the same jar to appcomapt libs folder if you are referencing Appcompat

Comment: @HakHak do you reference `AppCompat`. Do copy the same jar to AppCompat libs folder also.

Comment: what im saying is the lib that should be in support folder is there but i have another folder named "m2repository" and the libs that are found in support folder is also found in "m2repository" folder.maybe they are contradicting each other ill try deleting one of them. yes i have android-support-v7-appcompat and i put it in my app

Comment: what should i copy and where should i paste them