# Jar mismatch error ! fix your dependencies

Tags: android, jar, sdk, dependencies

i am not able to understand the y is causing issues when i remove  D:\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar error comes so any other solution to fix dependencies

```
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the    dependency list,
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ] Versions found are:
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ] Path:D:\backup\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ]    Length: 556198
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ]    SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ] Path: D:\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ]    Length: 627582
[2014-04-04 11:51:05 - ]    SHA-1: db0f122c99ef9f90dbab3fada6d191f2880cbb8e
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Jar+mismatch+error+!+fix+ur+dependencies&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=1FE-U9SxDabO8gfn0YGQDg

Comment: there is two library. You need to delete one.

Comment: @tinos07, try my below solution and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jar mismatch from log cat on program run using google play service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707722/jar-mismatch-from-log-cat-on-program-run-using-google-play-service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just **delete** `android-support-v4.jar` from your project's `libs` folder.
Then **copy** *`adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar`* file and **paste** it to your *`libs`* folder. Just *`clean and build`* your project !!

**YOU HAVE TO DO THIS TASK FOR BOTH `appcompat_v7` AND `Megavenues`.**

**No need to set Build Path.**

This works for me. 

I hop it will useful for you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Error you are getting because you have 2 set of **android-support-v4.jar**

I think you have also added some library project in your project that's why you are getting this error,

just delete **android-support-v4.jar** from your main project then go to android project proertie's select **Java Build path** and click on **Add external jar** and select **android-support-v4.jar** from you library project and click on Ok, also goto **Order and Export** tab after doing this all and select means just check mark your **android-support-v4.jar** then clean and build your project and check.

This solution did the trick for me.

Comment: @InnocentKillerv:: any of android-support-v4.jar file will work write

Comment: its not working bro when i delete one of the android-support-v4.jar file, eclipse ask me to import R!!!

Comment: Then have you added new android-support-v4.jar, then clean it and then try, surely it will work.

Comment: No, goto, `\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4` and copy that jar and paste it to your libary project's lib folder.

Comment: hey bro i tried that but still it didnt work , look at the correct marked qustion it really worked though m not fully convinced with the ans do u have any other way to solve this

Comment: Well, in my case this works, but anyway you solved your problem is great, go ahead.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Delete android-support-v4.jar from lib folder and build path, then clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the `android-support-v4.jar` from your project and paste the `android-support-v4.jar` of your library project in your main project.You can't do it directly in your eclipse you have to do it manually while going into your work space folder of the window explorer

Answer (score 0):

this is happened, if you use external library which have android-support-v4.jar, for this **copy 'android-support-v4.jar' from your project libs dir to external library libs folder**. this will solved error.