# Test Google Play Service with unsigned APK

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm coding an android game which is currently in progress. In the final version of the game I want to add a Google Play Service but I want to test this now.

My problem is, that I have to upload a signed apk to the Google Developer Console and I have to use the same signed apk to login. But if I change something on my code and install it via usb debugging the unsigned apk is installed and I can not test the Google Play Service. Is there a way to do all this with an unsigned apk?

Comment: You might want to look at this item instead: [Change the debug keystore to signed keystore][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886814/configure-eclipse-to-use-signed-keystore

Answer (score 2):

My app uses the Google Maps API and relies on Google Play. Simply create a second key that you can use in your development versions. In my Manifest file I have (as comments) the two api keys and if I want to test it in development mode I simply update the key in there. Also, be sure to 'clear data' and uninstall your production app before running the development version otherwise it will use the development key.

Comment: What do you mean with key? I only have the gameID in my manifest file.

Comment: Nevermind, the key is probably just google maps specific. Still, you should be able to test with the development version by removing the production version from your device first.